# Rendering html content in datatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, datatables, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am loading server response in a `datatable` using js in a asp.net core razor page. Because the data/UI is complex, I need to render different layouts based on current value in each table cell.

Datatable supports a `renderer` function for each cell, so I could have something like:

```
...
"data":"somefield",
"renderer":function(data,type,row,meta){
       if (data.someId)=="someValue"{
          return "<div... some label with somValue</div>"
       }else{
           return "<div... some label without value</div>"
       }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however when `divs` get complex with style and many labels it becomes harder to maintain or change.

I did look a bit into Razor's `PartialViews` as it may seem like a good alternative. Having the UI in a `cshtml` file, being able to pass parameters from parent `@Model` and using c# in it to render it based on the parameter received.

While I am able to load the partial view in the parent page, using `<partial name=''/>` or `@Html.Partial(...)` I didn't manage to get it's content in js using `$.get` and return it in the datatable's render function. Probably async wouldn't work in this case? Or it would be too slow?

My question is: what would be a better way to handle this situation? Maybe partial views are not the way. I am looking for a way of easily maintaining/changing the cell content. Thank you for  your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with `asp.net` but I will try to answer your question.

I don't think `PartialViews` are going to work in the way you suggest because they appear to be server-side code, and trying to do a `GET` request for every line in your table could potentially generate a large number of server requests.

I think you have a couple of potential solutions. First is to loop through your data on the server, and for each property that matches the condition generate the partial view and assign it to the property. Then return your data array with one of the properties in each row being a chunk of HTML. As I said, I don't have experience with this language so it's hard for me to provide a code example, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Then in DataTables you just need to output the value

```js
columns: [
    { data: 'someField' }
]
```

THe second option is to generate the HTML on the client using JavaScript. Since you say that it could be complex it's best if you have a function that returns a HTML string. If it's a large amount of HTML then you could even put this function in a separate file and export it, to make it more manageable. There are a couple of typos in your example, so I'm going to fix them here. `Renderer` is a table property, the one you want is [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Also in the `render` function the `data` argument references the `data` property that is defined in the line above. If you want to reference a different property, use the `row` argument.

```js
columns: [
    {
        data: 'someField',
        render: (data, type, row) => renderMyData(data, row)
    }
]
```

```js
function renderMyData(data, row) {
    if (row.someId == "someValue") {
        return "<div...> some label with somValue</div>"
    } else {
        return "<div...> some label without value</div>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  @mark_b for  taking your time to answer me. Generating on server side is not a solution indeed. My actual issue with html strings returned from a function is that: 1. there is no intelisense in writing these strings. 2. are hard to update and syntax can easily break. Maybe there is a way of writing these that I am not aware of. Could you please share an example? Thank you.

Comment: @Alin did you consider my first proposal, where you generate the HTML serverside using a loop before you return the data? That way you only need to make a single HTTP request.